# Ember build error: Assertion Failed: [BUG] seen set should be available

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Trying to update a Rails/Ember app and running into this error:

```
Template Compiler Error (broccoli-persistent-filter:TemplateCompiler) in ember-basic-dropdown/templates/components/basic-dropdown/content.hbs

Assertion Failed: [BUG] seen set should be available
```

Googled far and wide, but have not been able to find a fix. The only thing I found was this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-basic-dropdown/issues/624). Downgrading to `3.20.0` did not solve the issue.

Relevant packages:

```
"ember-cli": "^3.27.0",
"ember-data": "~3.26.0",
```

Comment: Which version of ember-basic-dropdown?

Comment: I'm seeing 1.1.3 and 1.1.0 as dependencies for `ember-power-select`, `ember-bootstrap-controls`.

Answer (score 2):

Update ember-power-select to the latest version will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an issue with `ember-basic-dropdown`, you can use

```
npm ls ember-basic-dropdown
```

to find which packages is using it as a dependency (most probably `ember-power-select`.

Once you find out, update that package and the problem should be resolved.